# Fatal error: Call to a member function setAttribute() on null when creating form using zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Fatal error: Call to a member function setAttribute() on null in \module\Admin\view\admin\index\login.phtml  when trying to create form using Zend Framework

Can somebody help me with where am doing wrong. I pasted all the code.

```
\module\Admin\src\Admin\Controller\LoginController.php

class LoginController extends AbstractActionController
{
protected  $usersTable = null;

public function indexAction()
{
    return new ViewModel();
}

public function loginAction(){
    $form = new LoginForm();
    $form->get('submit')->setValue('Login');

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if($request->isPost()){
        $login = new Login();
        $form->setInputFilter($login->getInputFilter());
        $form->setData($request->getPost());

        if($form->isValid()){
            $login->exchangeArray($form->getData());
            $this->getLoginDetails()->saveLoginForm($login);

            // Redirect to list of albums
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('index');
        }

    }

    return array('form' => $form);
}
}

 \module\Admin\src\Admin\Form

 namespace Admin\Form;

 use Zend\Form\Form;

 class LoginForm extends Form
 {
 public function _construct()
 {

     parent::_construct('admin');

     $this->add(array(
         'name' => 'username',
         'type' => 'Text',
         'options' => array(
             'label' => 'Username',
             'id' => 'txtUsername',
         ),
     ));

     $this->add(array(
         'name' => 'password',
         'type' => 'password',
         'options' => array(
             'label' => 'Password',
             'id' => 'txtPassword',
         ),
     ));
     $this->add(array(
         'name' => 'submit',
         'type' => 'Submit',
         'attributes' => array(
             'value' => 'Login',
             'id' => 'btnSubmit',
         ),
     ));
 }
 }

\module\Admin\src\Admin\Model

namespace Admin\Model;

use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareInterface;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface;

class Login implements InputFilterAwareInterface{

public $username;
public $password;
protected $inputFilter;

public function exchangeArray($data)
{
    $this->artist = (isset($data['username'])) ? $data['username'] : null;
    $this->title  = (isset($data['password']))  ? $data['password']  : null;
}

public function setInputFilter(InputFilterInterface $inputFilter){
    throw new \Exception("not used");
}

public function getInputFilter(){
    if(!$this->inputFilter){
        $inputFilter = new InputFilter();

        $inputFilter->add(array(
            'name'     => 'username',
            'required' => true,
            'filters'  => array(
                array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
            ),
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name'    => 'StringLength',
                    'options' => array(
                        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                        'min'      => 1,
                        'max'      => 50,
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ));

        $inputFilter->add(array(
            'name'     => 'password',
            'required' => true,
            'filters'  => array(
                array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
            ),
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name'    => 'StringLength',
                    'options' => array(
                        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                        'min'      => 1,
                        'max'      => 50,
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ));

        $this->inputFilter = $inputFilter;
    }

    return $this->inputFilter;
}

\module\Admin\view\admin\index
<?php


$form = $this->form;

$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('admin', array('action' => 'login')));
$form->prepare();

echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
echo $this->formRow($form->get('username'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('password'));
echo $this->formSubmit($form->get('submit'));
echo $this->form()->closeTag();

echo $this->$form;
```

Answer (score 0):

What is $form = $this->form?
Is used in controller? Where do you pass anything on $this->form. Its null, like you see error. You can var_dump($form) to check it. You need to create your form first with:

```
$form = new \My\Form();
```

If $form is null inside login.phtml, thats mean you dont passed $form variable to phtml script (we dont see it in your code)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to change element attribute you have to get that element by using getElement function then use zend form function. Try below code it will work for you.

```
$form = new LoginForm();

$form->getElement('submit')->setValue('get');
```